# 僕 in 敬語 - is it possible?

Tags: politeness, keigo, pronouns, first-person-pronouns

With 丁寧語, it's very possible - 僕が行きます is a perfectly normal thing to say. But what of 僕が参ります? Would that sound odd? 私が参ります would be more normal, I think, but is 僕が参ります possible at all?

Comment: Just FYI, the 警護 you had means "protection" or "guard".

Comment: [丁寧語 is a type of 敬語.](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/150311/m0u/%E4%B8%81%E5%AF%A7%E8%AA%9E/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 僕 is not very respectful (to the listener). It's not exactly rude (you can use it with です・ます, after all) but it's a little relaxed.

**So, if you are using 尊敬語 or 謙譲語 to show respect to the listener, then I think 僕 does not fit** (normally you'd be using 私{わたくし} or some more relevant term like 弊社).

1. However, if you're using 尊敬語 to show respect to some third party then I think it's totally fine. For example,

   > **Manager to subordinate:**
   >   僕は先ほど社長がおっしゃった件についてまだ答えを出していない。
2. Also, I can think of at least one exception here, which is if a much older person is talking to someone much younger, but that younger person is still someone who you would still use a light 尊敬語 with... for example,

   > **Presenter (company A) to onlooker (company B):**
   >   僕の発表は以上です。どう思われましたか？ or ご質問はありますか？

   There might be other cases where the situation balances itself out enough (in this case, old -> young vs company -> unaffiliated company) that you could probably get some light/loose 尊敬語 where it might make sense to use 僕.

   As a note, if you are ever using 謙譲語 (like you are in your example), then I think that's already enough proof that the conversation is pretty formal in tone and you should not be using 僕. (Unless the 謙譲語 is being used sarcastically, of course.)

Comment: @Yuuwa Thanks for accepting, but I'd probably wait for input from a native speaker, since I'm probably not *really* qualified to answer this (non-native speaker who rarely ever uses or hears 敬語).